# What is the value of the PM segment in the figure below?

Tags: geometry

For reference:

Given a rectangle, ABCD (AB > BC) by B draws a perpendicular to AC which
intercepts "P" to CD, and an "M" the perpendicular to BD drawn by B.
$\space$ The prolongation of DM and BC intersect at Q.

Calculate PM if DQ =$ 17$ and BP = $9$. (answer: $4$)

[image]

My progresss:

$$\triangle BCP \sim \triangle QCD\\
\frac{BC}{CQ}=\frac{PC}{2PC}=\frac{PB}{DQ}\rightarrow\\
\frac{BC}{17}=\frac{1}{2}=\frac{9}{DQ} \therefore BC = \frac{17}{2}; DQ=18\\
\triangle DCQ: DC^2+CQ^2 = DQ^2 \rightarrow\\
DC^2+17^2 =18^2 \therefore DC =\sqrt35\\
\text{draw} ~MI \perp BQ \implies \triangle MBQ (\text{isosceles})\\
\triangle BMI \sim \triangle DCQ (AA):\\
BI = \frac{BQ}{2} = \frac{\frac{17}{2}+17}{2} =\frac{51}{4}\\\\
\frac{BI}{17}=\frac{BP+PM}{DQ}\rightarrow \frac{51}{68}=\frac{9+PM}{18} \therefore \boxed{ PM=4,5}$$

[image]

I didn't see where my mistake is..(book answer = 4)

Comment: why do you think DC=2PC?

Comment: @sirous  It is true. I thought it was midpoint but it's not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Hints: If you show that In figure M is midpoint of QT and DM=PM, then we have:

In right angled triangle TBQ, BM=MQ so:

$17-PM=9+PM\Rightarrow PM=4$

Comment: @ sirous..in my picture ..$\triangle MBQ ~ is~ isosceles  \therefore MB = MQ \rightarrow MI~ is~ middle ~base \therefore  M ~is~ midpoint~ QT~ \therefore QM = TM$  $ \triangle DPM~is~isosceles \therefore DP = MP $ . ..I didn't understand QM = 17 - PM???

Comment: @peta arantes , MD=MP not DP=MP. Then QM-MD=QM-MP=BM= BP+MP.

Comment: @sirous...grateful for the clarification and sorry for my difficulty in seeing myself... I have already created the drawing because it had an angle in the wrong position.